# Speed of Floating Point Arithmetic in Julia

Tags: julia

I found the speed of Float32 matrices in matrix-vector products faster by two times  than Float64 matrices. I tried to decrease the precision more to Float16 hoping I will get more speed, but the performance was a lot worse than Float64.

Comment: Well I know that modern architectures do not like half words, but that is more of a general statement. You may want to add more details to your question, maybe a small benchmark too. In fact, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Have you tried on machines with different different length of registers?

Comment: Floating point multiplication performance is largely dependent on your hardware.  Modern hardware supports 32 bit and 64 bit floating point, but not 16 bit.  So Float16 would be a software implementation.  Shrug.  Move on.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Julia does most `Float16` operations by converting to `Float32` and then converting back. This also means that it can't use `BLAS` doesn't get used for matrix operations and instead generic fallbacks are used. That said, I think `Float16` might produce efficient code on GPU with Julia.

Comment: It should be noted that this is because current CPUs don't support Float16, so there's no way to do Float16 operations in hardware on CPUs. GPUs on the other hand, have native Float16 and operations on them will be much faster there.

Comment: Thinking about this a little, it should be possible to make `Float16` matrix vector products really fast. Storing the data in `Float16` could have better cache usage, and you could do a vectorized conversion. It would be a ton of work though...